# Стилизация input type range

Tags: css, css3

Работал над стилизацией этого элемента, столкнулся с проблемой, что нужно сделать progress линию слева от ползунка оранжевого цвета, использовать box-shadow я не могу, так как не могу поставить на input overflow: hidden, у меня кружок thumb вылазит за блок, это его обрежет, без overflow тень превращается в кошмар
Вот код который работает сейчас :

```css
#radius,
#radius-2 {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to right,
        #f2622d 0%,
        #f2622d 50%,
        transparent 50%,
        transparent 100%
    );
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-position: right;
    transition: background-position 0.3s ease;
}

#radius:hover,
#radius-2:hover {
    background-position: left;
}

#radius::-webkit-slider-thumb,
#radius-2::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background-color: #f2622d;
    border: 0px solid #f2622d;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    margin-top: -7px;
}

#radius::-moz-range-thumb,
#radius-2::-moz-range-thumb {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background-color: #f2622d;
    border: 0px solid #f2622d;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    margin-top: -7px;
}

#radius::-webkit-slider-runnable-track,
#radius-2::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    height: 4px;
    border: 0px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #353535;
    background: #d7d7d7;
}
```

Таким образом это должно выглядеть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я имею сейчас :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: думаю [тут](https://brennaobrien.com/blog/2014/05/style-input-type-range-in-every-browser.html) то что Вам нужно

Comment: К сожалению не работает, попробовал, нет никаких изменений

Comment: Это html css jQuery, если вы знаете библиотеку на jq которая сможет это сделать, будет прекрасно

Comment: посмотрите [тут](https://codepen.io/ChrisBup/pen/jOEpJqv)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте clip-path и box-shadow:

```css
#radius,
#radius-2 {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 250px;
    height: 18px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#radius::-webkit-slider-thumb,
#radius-2::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background-color: #f2622d;
    border: 0px solid #f2622d;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    margin-top: -7px;
    box-shadow: calc(-100vmax - 18px) 0 0 100vmax #f2622d;
    clip-path: polygon(
        100% 0,
        2px 0,
        0 7px,
        -100vmax 7px,
        -100vmax 11px,
        0 11px,
        2px 100%,
        100% 100%
    );
}

#radius::-moz-range-thumb,
#radius-2::-moz-range-thumb {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background-color: #f2622d;
    border: 0px solid #f2622d;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    margin-top: -7px;
}

#radius::-webkit-slider-runnable-track,
#radius-2::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    height: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 0px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #353535;
    background: #d7d7d7;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="radius">
```